# How to make the new document visible after creating from a template?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I use the macro Word letter template to generate customized letters. After I run the macro, the new document is not in focus, and is behind other documents that are opened.

1. The new document hasn't been saved, so the name of the document is "Document XX"
2. I tried ActiveDocument.Activate, and the code below. The letter template is a macro userform.

```vb
Dim odoc As Document
Set odoc = Documents.Add("\\XXXX\LetterTemplate.dotx", Visible:=True)
```

How do I bring the active document into view?

Answer (score 0):

### The Active Document is already active.

Try:

`oDoc.Activate`

It should have become the active document when created and at the front. Do you have other code involving screenupdating?

Comment: Yes. I turned off the screen refresh/updating, but that didn't change anything. maybe I'm adding the oDoc.Active info incorrectly?? I was adding the code in the cmdAddLetter_click code on the userform. Otherwise, I don't have any other macros besides the one's on the userform.

Comment: oDoc.Activate should work when in the code after you have created the document by setting oDoc. It would help if you shared all the code. Perhaps also put a cleaned-out version of the template with the code in a zip folder on DropBox and post a view link here as well.

Comment: Okay so I used ActiveDocument.Activate at the end of my code in my cmdGo_Click code of my userform. So far it seems to be working. Thanks for your help Charles

Answer (score 0):

A radical approach is to minimize all open application windows. Then when your code opens a document, it will be the only window displayed.

```
Sub MinimizeAll()
    Dim shell As Object
    Set shell = CreateObject("shell.application")
    shell.MinimizeAll
    Set shell = Nothing
End Sub
```

You and your end-users will have to decide if that is an acceptable approach because this can be an annoying solution on two-monitor systems.

Comment: Thanks Rich! This is a little too much for me. I just need the dang active document to go back to the active window. I have seen this issue with other Word docs that are created via userforms. It's got to be in my userform code.